# Como criar uma função anônima (Closure) recursiva?

Tags: php, funções, função-anônima, recursão

No php, podemos criar funções com recursividade da seguinte forma.

```
function quack($quack = 1)
{

    if ($quacks >= 1) {
      echo "Quack";
      $quack--;
      quack($quacks);
    }
}
```

Ou, em caso de evitar problema com "renomeações" da função.

```
function quack($quack = 1)
{ 

   $func = __FUNCTION__;

    if ($quacks >= 1) {
      echo "Quack";
      $quack--;
      $func($quacks);
    }
}
```

Mas, e quando se trata de funções anônimas?

Exemplo:

```
$quack = function ($quacks)
{
   if ($quacks >= 1) {
      echo "Quack";
      $quacks--;
       // como chamo $quack aqui?
   }
}
```

Como eu poderia tornar a função anônima `$quack` em uma função recursiva?

Comment: Vamos ver se alguém mata essa charada :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basta atribuir sua função anônima a uma variável e passar essa variável por referência.

Tomemos por exemplo uma função anônica que calcula o fatorial de um valor:

```
$factorial = function($n) use(&$factorial) {
    if ($n == 1) return 1;
    return $factorial($n - 1) * $n;
};
```

Então chamamos essa função por meio da variável à qual a mesma está atribuida:

```
print $factorial(4); // 24
```

Vi nessa resposta do SOEn: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480179/anonymous-recursive-php-functions